# Google Glass Video Streaming with MediaCodec

Tags: video-streaming, google-glass, google-gdk

I am working on an application for live video streaming using Google Glass.
Using libstreaming 3.0, H264 encoding and MediaCodec API the buffer obtained is sometimes null.
If I am not mistaking, is seems that the video encoder on Glass is too slow.

Using MediaRecorder API and H264 encoding, the streaming works, but the quality and lag are not satisfactory.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a good solution for live video streaming from Glass using MediaCodec API and H264 encoding?

Comment: What resolution are you trying for?